# Can't update value of nested Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested

I am trying to update a value in a complex `Dictionary` of unknown type, as it contains both `String`s and sub-dictionaries. My initialisation function code is below.

*This is what my `Dictionary` looks like before:*

```
var methods = [
    "PUN": [
        "name": "Time of PUN",
        "params": ["FJ": 18, "IS": 17]
    ],
    "KHR": [
        "name": "Time KHR",
        "params": ["FJ": 15, "IS": 15]
    ],
    "LHR": [
        "name": "Time of LHR",
        "params": ["FJ": 19.5, "IS": 17.5 , "MG": 8.9]
    ]
]
```

*This is what I want to achieve, dynamically:*

```
var methods = [
    "PUN": [
        "name": "Time of PUN",
        "params": ["FJ": 18, "IS": 17, "Offset": "0 min", "Midnight": "Standard"]
    ],
    "KHR": [
        "name": "Time KHR",
        "params": ["FJ": 15, "IS": 15, "Offset": "0 min", "Midnight": "Standard"]
    ],
    "LHR": [
        "name": "Time of LHR",
        "params": ["FJ": 19.5, "IS": 17.5 , "MG":8.9, "Offset": "0 min", "Midnight": "Standard"]
    ]
]
```

This is my code:

*I am taking extra values from `defaultParams` (`Dictionary`) and inserting into `methods` (`Dictionary`).*

```
var methods = [String: AnyObject]()
let defaultParams = ["Offset": "0 min", "Midnight": "Standard"]

init() { 
    methods["Punjab"] = [
        "name": "Punjab Time",
        "params": ["FJ": 18, "IS": 17]
    ]

    methods["Karachi"] = [
        "name": "Time of Karachi",
        "params": ["FJ": 15, "IS": 15]
    ]

    methods["Lahore"] = [
        "name": "Lahore City Time",
        "params": ["FJ": 19.5, "IS": 17.5 , "MG": 8.9]
    ]     

    for (methodName, methodValue) in methods {
        var params = methodValue["params"]!!

        for (defaultParamKey, defaultParamValue) in defaultParams {
            if params.objectForKey(defaultParamKey) == nil {
                // I am having problem with the line below, it says 
                // cannot asign a value of type String to a value of type AnyObject?!
                params[defaultParamKey] = defaultParamValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*On initialization I just want to insert the missing values in dictionary variable `methods` by checking it with variable `defaultParams`.*

Comment: What should go where? It's not clear. Please explain what you want in details.

Comment: Why vote -1 I thought this community is for helping people or is it just for critisizing and downvoting, if someone don't understand I can explain it further. If people keep downvoting genuine question like this than what's the point of keeping this site alive. I did my research and waisted lot of time before coming here and asking for help.

Comment: The init function above is the one getting called. and the variable named method is the one I want to modify inside the init()

Comment: lets say in plain language I want to do this:--  methods["params"]["Offset"] = "TEST"   .  I would basically want to add an extra key to the methods variable and a corresponding value as well

Comment: The "offset" doesn't exist in the methods["params"] but I want to put it in and give it a value "TEST"

Comment: @EricD. I have updated the question can you please have a look again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted but it works:

```
class Test {
    var methods = [String: [String: AnyObject]]()
    let defaultParams = ["Offset": "0 min", "Midnight": "Standard"]

    init() {
        methods["Punjab"] = [
            "name": "Punjab Time",
            "params": ["FJ": 18, "IS": 17]
        ]

        methods["Karachi"] = [
            "name": "Time of Karachi",
            "params": ["FJ": 15, "IS": 15]
        ]

        methods["Lahore"] = [
            "name": "Lahore City Time",
            "params": ["FJ": 19.5, "IS": 17.5 , "MG": 8.9]
        ]

        for (methodName, methodValue) in methods {

            for (mKey, mValue) in methodValue {

                if mKey == "params" {

                    var pDic = mValue as! [String: AnyObject]

                    for (defaultKey, defaultValue) in defaultParams {

                        if !contains(pDic.keys, defaultKey) {

                            pDic[defaultKey] = defaultValue

                            methods[methodName]!["params"]! = pDic

                        }

                    }



                }

            }

        }
    }
}

let t = Test()
println(t.methods)
```

Result:

> [Karachi: [params: {
>       FJ = 15;
>       IS = 15;
>       Midnight = Standard;
>       Offset = "0 min";
>   }, name: Time of Karachi], Punjab: [params: {
>       FJ = 18;
>       IS = 17;
>       Midnight = Standard;
>       Offset = "0 min";
>   }, name: Punjab Time], Lahore: [params: {
>       FJ = "19.5";
>       IS = "17.5";
>       MG = "8.9";
>       Midnight = Standard;
>       Offset = "0 min";
>   }, name: Lahore City Time]]

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `== nil` , you should use `if let` closure, i don't know which value you want to assign, but that approach would work.

```
if let value = params.objectForKey(defaultParamKey) as? String {
           params[defaultParamKey] = value
}
```

Comment: getting this error again: cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!'

Comment: In addition to that the above code of yours will only execute if the key is present in the methods["params"] whereas my problem is that I want to add missing keys and values in the methods["params"] by comparing it with defaultParams , i.e these ones(["Offset": "0 min", "Midnight": "Standard"])